# How can I make C-j send a newline in the tmux command line?

Tags: tmux, key-mapping

I have grown fond of using `C-j` instead of `<ENTER>` to send newlines. Unfortunately, in the tmux command line (invoked with `prefix-:` by default), `C-j` does not do anything, even with `set -gw status-keys emacs` placed in `~/.tmux.conf`. (Note that `C-j` sends newlines for me in bash and I also have it mapped in other programs without trouble.)

So, referring to the title of the question: *How can I make `C-j` send a newline in the tmux command line?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrade to tmux 1.9a which contains the following change making `C-j` the same as `C-m`: https://secure.freshbsd.org/commit/openbsd/8b7f9bdcbac2b1eb7c3a918af2cb7cd7c7b315e4

Comment: @Ramesh The relevant details are "C-j behaves the same as C-m"; including the actual diff lines doesn't seem particularly helpful

Comment: It's been two years *to the day* since you answered this question, and I just now got around to checking it again. You were right! Sorry for taking so long to accept your answer.